# Hoping to boost traffic to NFP site. SEO info? HELP!

Tags: optimization, seo, traffic, marketing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to increase your site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-your-sites-position-in-google)

I'm doing work for a not-for-profit looking to boost traffic to the site. I need to learn a tremendous amount about SEO and backlinking in a short length of time.

Any tips you can give me, or sites you can refer me to, I'll be most grateful.

A million thanks,
Chaz

Comment: Not programming related, and not even a question at that...

Comment: Just google "SEO Tutorial" or whatever. Your question is way too general.